# Is there a performance difference between running a PHP script via CLI and via webserver?

Tags: php, performance

Is it different to run a php script using e.g., `/usr/sbin/php myscript.php`

or using a web server e.g., `http://127.0.0.1/myscript.php`?

By "different" I refer to the time of the response; who wins?

Comment: There will be no difference, it's the same PHP either way. One might be slightly slower to invoke than the other, but the performance of your PHP code will be identical.

Answer (score 4):

Could be both.

The former because: There is no webserver + http + tcp overhead.

The latter because: The PHP process may already be started (FastCGI).

Thus: Don't guess, profile!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're different. You don't have a web server environment wrapped around the command line version, so many values in $_SERVER will be absent/different, and the web-related super-globals will be empty.

As well, command line may be faster than the web version, as you don't have the TCP/IP and HTTP overhead to deal with, but that all depends on how the command line PHP is configured versus the in-server version. The command line version could be loading hundreds of extra modules, while the web version is a stripped down/lean/mean installation.